# Array initialization without comma

Tags: c, string, pointers, cstring

In the following code I am having the output like(last one giving segmentation fault)

```
 U   
 s    
 HelloThisisatest    
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but i do not understand why.
code is

```
int main()
{
   char *a[]={"Hello" "This" "is" "a" "test"};
   printf("%c\n",a[1][0]);
   printf("%c\n",a[0][8]);
   printf("%s\n",a[0]);
   printf("%s\n",a[3]);
   return 0;
}
```

Another question is that can we initialize an 2-D array without using comma?
Another situation that I got that when i am replacing the `\n`s by `\t`s then output changes like

"U  s   HelloThisisatest    (null)"

why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because in C, two adjacent strings are concatenated into one. So "Hello" "World" is actually a single string "HelloWorld".

- In your case The array of pointer actually contains one single string "HelloThisisatest". In the first printf you are accessing the location 1, which is undefined behaviour.
- The next printf accesses the character 8 of the string which is `s` .
- The third printf prints the entire string stored on the location `0`, which is "HelloThisisatest"
- The last printf attempts to access the array location 3, which is undefined behavour, as it is not initialized.

**EDIT**

Refer C11/C99 standard Section 5.1.1.2 Paragraph 6, which tells:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of pointers to char.  However, there is only one such pointer, so code like:

```
a[1][0]
```

overruns the array.  The first index must always be 0 for this particular array.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to do this:

```
char a[][20] = {"Hello", "This", "is", "a", "test"};
```

notice that the second dimension should have a size (`20`)

now you can print all the words:

```
printf("%s\n",a[0]);
printf("%s\n",a[1]);
printf("%s\n",a[2]);
printf("%s\n",a[3]);
printf("%s\n",a[4]);
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour, starts from `a[1]`

Comment: `a[1]`, `[2]`, etc are not initialized.

Comment: they are! see, I've added comma after each word